# Runtime Error 1004: tables cannot over lap

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to record a macro of Power Query refreshing itself. Whenever I run that code it gives me the error that tables cannot overlap

> Run time error '1004' A table cannot over lap another table

I tried this to debug, but didn't work either

```
Windows("WorkOrderItemOpen2.0.xlsm").Activate
Sheets("Valid Labor").Activate

With ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(SourceType:=0, Source:= _
    "OLEDB;Provider=Microsoft.Mashup.OleDb.1;Data Source=$Workbook$;Location=Merge1;Extended Properties=""""" _
    , Destination:=Sheets("Valid Labor").Range("$A$1")).QueryTable
    .CommandType = xlCmdSql
    .CommandText = Array("SELECT * FROM [Merge1]")
    .RowNumbers = False
    .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
    .PreserveFormatting = True
    .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
    .BackgroundQuery = True
    .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
    .SavePassword = False
    .SaveData = True
    .AdjustColumnWidth = True
    .RefreshPeriod = 0
    .PreserveColumnInfo = True
    .ListObject.DisplayName = "Merge1"
    .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=True

End With
```

Comment: Did you try pasting it on a new sheet instead of `Valid Labor` ?

Comment: Yeah, I did, changed the sheets to a new one but the location Merge1 is set on the original sheet. Event I rename the Location = Merge 2 as a different one it still doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

You are adding a new ListObject (table) every time you are running the code, but the previous table remains in the sheet (at the very same place). As you cannot have overlapping tables, you get the error.

If you only want to refresh the data, all you have to do is call the refresh-method of the ListObject, e.g

```
ActiveSheet.ListObjects(1).refresh()
```